# Yii2 - facing issue with default password length validation

Tags: php, yii2

In my signup form model ,i have not added Minimum Password length validator. but still i am getting it as validation error. can anyone help to solve this . how to stop that validation execution even though i have not added it in rules array. below is my code.

```
    <?php

namespace app\models;

use app\models\User;
use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;

/**
 * Signup form
 */
class SignupForm extends Model {

    public $username;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $password_repeat;
    public $unit_id;
    public $timezone;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules() {
        $array_rule = [
            ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['username', 'required'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\app\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],
            ['unit_id', 'integer'],
            ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\app\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],
           ];
return $array_rule;
    }

public function signup() {
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            print_r($this->getErrors());
        }
}
}?>
```

Comment: Must be set somewhere else.

Comment: where ?? does yii2 default set it inside its core code structure ??

Comment: No, I mean like in parent class or target model class.

Comment: no, i haven't set it at anywhere so if in any yii2 core model it is going to set than how to make it strict that its not going to validate ?

Comment: Please post your signup model.

Comment: @Mitesh: It would be good if you construct your query properly Like proper section for question , scenario and stuff. you should have posted Signup model as Bizley asked. Helps us first to understand your work done :)

Comment: Model code is updated above. in signup function where i have print error message , i am getting " Password should contain at least 6 characters. ".
even i have not added any rules for password on rules(). @AnkurSoni , Bizley

Comment: Search String "Password should contain at least 6 characters." in entire project, you'll get your answer, I guess.

Comment: Better to set password in rules so that it should work according to your need. just set it as a string and don't set max value and then try it.

Comment: @AwaisMustafa but i don't want any rule related to password. and this is coming from defult yii2 core code part from vendor/yii2.
so is there any way to we can avoid this default yii2 password validation execution ?

Comment: For over ruling defaultvalidations, you will have to write something so if you want your password to be less than 6 chars then set the min length in a rule for password, but you must have a rule.

Answer (score 1):

You must add rules for password field, then could be loaded via $model->load

so add to rules array:

```
['password','safe'] or ['passwprd','string','min'=>5,'mix'=>50];
```